# Probability for odd and even with floor function

Tags: probability

I'm self teaching probability and struggling to get started with this question:

Consider a random variable $U : Ω → R$ that is defined on a probability space (Ω, F, P)
and that is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. For n ≥ 1, let $B_n = 1$ if $⌊2^nU⌋$ is an odd
integer and $B_n = 0$ otherwise.

Show that $B_n, n ≥ 1$, is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $P(B_n = 0) = P(Bn = 1) = 1/2$

The answer should make sense due to the floor function, but I'm really not sure how to go about showing this.

Comment: Well...how does it work out for $B_1$?  What about $B_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case $n=1$. In this instance, we have
$$
P(\lfloor2U\rfloor = 0) = \int_0^\frac{1}{2}\, dx = \frac{1}{2}, \\
P(\lfloor2U\rfloor = 1) = \int_\frac{1}{2}^1\, dx = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
When $n = 2$, we have
$$
P(\lfloor4U\rfloor = 0) = \int_0^\frac{1}{4}\, dx = \frac{1}{4}, \\
P(\lfloor4U\rfloor = 1) = \int_\frac{1}{4}^\frac{1}{2}\, dx = \frac{1}{4},\\
P(\lfloor4U\rfloor = 2) = \int_\frac{1}{2}^\frac{3}{4}\, dx = \frac{1}{4}, \\
P(\lfloor4U\rfloor = 3) = \int_\frac{3}{4}^1\, dx = \frac{1}{4}.
$$
For general $n$, we have
$$
P(\lfloor2^nU\rfloor = i) = \int_\frac{i}{2^n}^\frac{i+1}{2^n}\, dx = \frac{1}{2^n}, \,0\leq i < 2^n
$$
So,
$$
P(B_n = 0) = \sum_{i=0}^{2^{n-1}-1} P(\lfloor2^nU\rfloor = 2i) = 2^{n-1}  \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
And similarly for $P(B_n = 1)$.